# Multiple parameter route not matching

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Can someone please explain to me why this route :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ListingDetails",
    "{city}-{propertyType}-for-sale-MLS-{mlsId}",
    new {controller= "Search", action="Details"}
    );
```

Does not match this action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int mlsId, string city, string propertyType, string mls)
        {
            var listing = _listingService.GetListingByMlsId(mlsId);
            return View(listing);
        }
```

I've listed the route as the first one, so there is no route before it that is capturing it. Instead of it matching I'm just getting Search/Details?mlsId=...&propertyType=...

Answer (score 1):

The `mls` argument is the culprit. You should be able to fix it by assigning a default value to the `mls` argument:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(... string mls = "something")
```

Or defining a default value in the route:

```
new {controller= "Search", action="Details", mls="something"}
```